# git | how to sync local repo with remote repo?

Tags: git, cron, githooks

I have my local git repo that and I want to attach it to a remote git repo in a way that the remote will be like a read only version of the local git repo and will present everything in the local git repository automaticlly, without the need to push from local to remote.
Meaning, if I add a new file in the local repo I will be able see the change immedietly in my remote repo before I commited or push.

I tried git hooks, but it seems that none of them fits.
Actually the action I need to do is on every file that is removed or added to my local git folder to run this set of commands:
"git add <file_name> ; git commit -m "auto commit" ; git push"

what is the best way to implement this solution?

thank you!

Comment: Consider usin svn

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Are you sure it's only add/removes? What about edits? If you edit a file I assume you would want that change "synced" too?

Answer (score 0):

You can't not do a push to have the remote up-to-date with your local.

You will want to create a git alias for adding new files to do the string of commands.  Using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25915221/498699

In your `.gitconfig` add this:

```
[alias] create = !git add $1; git commit -m "auto commit"; git push && :
```

Now you can run `git create file1` and it will run those commands.

For updating tracked files, add a `post-commit` hook that runs `git push` after successfully doing a commit.