# How to do a "git checkout -b <branchname>" from a remote tag

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm trying to create a branch from a remote tag, but it seems there's no way to do it. When I try

```
git checkout -b test origin/deploy
```

where origin is the remote and deploy is the tag I want to check out, but I get

```
fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/deploy' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

**UPDATE:**
I've just discovered that

```
git fetch --all -t
```

was not working properly for me. While it downloads all branches, it does not download all tags, so when I checked out deploy it was and old tag. Now I execute

```
git fetch --all && git fetch -t
```

This way when I create a new branch based on a tag

```
git checkout -b test deploy
```

the new branch is up to date with the last deploy.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not a git guru, but I had used something like this before and it seemed to have worked fine:

```
git pull (or fetch, just need to make sure you are updated)
git checkout -b test remotes/origin/deploy
```

Comment: this is not working for me (MacOs X, remote is hosted at github) I get: fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch '6.2.3-ga4' at the same time.

Comment: Make sure the branch you are trying to track exists.  i.e. first do a git fetch, or git pull, or git remote update, etc..

Answer (score 30):

I'm not sure you can do this directly. You're probably stuck with doing a fetch and then a checkout:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b test tag-name
```

By the way, I wouldn't recommend using a tag name like "deploy".

Comment: Well, now I'm always doing "git fetch --all -t" before the checkout, but in some cases the branches created from the tag seem to be pointing to an old deploy instead of the last one.

BTW, why wouldn't you use the name "deploy"?

Comment: @Sergi, tags are intended to remain fixed, but a name like "deploy" implies you will be changing it frequently.  It's better to use a branch to label a line of development that changes over time, and have your tags be specific versions, like "1.0".

Comment: @Joost, oh, don't worry then. I always create two tags when I deploy, one with the version name, and another one called deploy, which is overwritten each time I make a new deploy. This way the rest of developers could branch from the last good point on the deployment branch.

Any idea why sometimes do I get branches pointing to and old deploy? Could it be that the "git fetch --all -t" is not working as expected?

Comment: I don't know how duplicate tags are resolved. It's implied tags are supposed to be fixed and unique. I found that using a "deploy" branch with tags for specific releases works very well; that way you have something that always points to the current release (the HEAD of that branch) and fixed references to past releases (tags with version number or dates).

Comment: @Sergi, you can do as you like.  But the Git documentation is very explicit about the fact that tags shouldn't be changed or reused.  From the git-tag documentation: "If somebody got a release tag from you, you cannot just change the tag for them by updating your own one. This is a big security issue, in that people MUST be able to trust their tag-names. If you really want to do the insane thing, you need to just fess up to it, and tell people that you messed up. You can do that by making a very public announcement saying: [...example given]"

Comment: BTW, I just discovered that "git fetch --all -t" and "git fetch --all && git fetch -t" does not return the same result. The first one does not get all tags, while the second one does.

Answer (score 5):

You need to run

```
git pull
git checkout -b <new-branch-name> remotes/origin/<source-branch-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

to list all the tags

```
git fetch
git tags -l
```

to create a local branch that points to the tag

```
git checkout tags/<tag_name> -b <branch_name>
git checkout -b <branch_name> tags/<tag_name>
```