# Sourcetree/git to not show closed remote branches

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Is it possible to hide closed remote brances in sourcetree? I would not want the remote section to show all old remotes, which has really been closed already.

Comment: `git` has no concept of an "open" vs "closed" branch. It does, however allow for deleting a branch pointer, or renaming a branch pointer, possibly with a name like "closed/originalbranchname"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242924/how-to-close-a-branch-without-removing-it-from-history-in-git) seems like you cannot close a branch on git.

One workaround is that you can rename your branches from bName to oldClosedBranches/bName then you will keep just one 'folder' for all of them.

[Rename-master-branch-for-both-local-and-remote-git-repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526794/rename-master-branch-for-both-local-and-remote-git-repositories)