# Clean large pack-refs after many branches where "archived"

Tags: git, performance, tortoisegit

I recently "archived" (created `archive/tag` and removed branch - following [How can I archive git branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307114/how-can-i-archive-git-branches)) a large set of branches.

However, this did not solved one of my issues, which was the large number of lines I had to scroll through in [tortoisegit](/questions/tagged/tortoisegit) when performing some action (here: merge: [image: tortoisegit lots of refs].

I see all these branches in Tortoise, even if they do not show locally or remotely with the `git branch -a` command:

### Question

How is it possible to reset this set of references without having to clone the entire repo.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to clean up remote tracked references which are deleted on the remote side perform a fetch with prune (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-pull.html)

FYI: TortoiseGit executes `git.exe for-each-ref` to list all references, so they are still there in the repository.

Comment: Oh... This is what "prune" was meant for. Always thought the thing was enable at the time I fetched. But it wasn't! it was using the default. Great Mr. TUx.

Answer (score 0):

The TortoiseGit solution [suggested above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63575934/6019417) works well.

I also found a "plain git command" solution:

- remove the reference file
- force git to re-create it.

---

```
mv .git/packed-refs .git/packed-refs-bak
git fetch
git pack-refs --all
```