# How do I hide inactive branches from the sidebar

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

In the Sourcetree UI the sidebar has a list of all branches, we will be having alot of branches eventually since we will be doing weekly branches which we have to be able to recreate in the future (so we cant delete them after merged back into master).

So is it possible to hide a branch or should we just accept that we will have a long and growing list of branches in the sidepanel ?

I looked thourh the sourcetrees FAQ and answers, nothing quite solved it.

As far as I can tell you have to actually delete a branch to remove it from the sidepanel, which is not a solution for us as we need to be able to recreate old branches.

Comment: This is a process question more than a programming question. You should only keep branches that are still under development. Based on your SDLC, as your `feature` branches are merged through to production and released, you should never go back to them. They should be deleted after the final merge in order to stop being out of date. However, as long as the most recent changes have been pushed to your `remote` server, you should be good to delete those branches locally.

Comment: Archive the branches to tags and then hide tags in the UI (or specficially tags with prefix `archive/`), perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/1309934/1725151

Comment: I think there is a feature request for this in Sourcetree for Mac: 
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-2977