# How to see all archived branches in Git

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Is there a way to see all the branches that are archived?
I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65468244/9974143) to archive some of my branches.
and there's a way to restore the branch after I have archived it, but only if I know the name. If I don't know the name, is there a way to see all branch names that have been archived?

some sort of

```
git branch -archive
```

Comment: maybe git branch --list 'archive/*' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the answer you linked, the "archive" operation is made by creating `tags` on each branch to be archived and then removing such a branches. So, after all you have no branches, you have only tags.

To list all tags with `archive` prefix in the name you can use

```
git tag -l "archive/*"
```

(note the `archive` part of command - it should match with a word you used when creating archive tags.

So, finally, to restore some archived branch from a tag (for example, named `archive/test123`) you can use

```
git checkout -b test123 archive/test123
```